# cudMemcpy invalid argument no clues about what is wrong

Tags: c++, cuda

I wrote some code and can't get it work for some reason...but it's already copy paste from working test program generated by VisualStudio:

```
__device__ int pseudoRandomFunction(int seed)
{
    unsigned int m_w = 150;
    unsigned int m_z = 40;

    m_z = 36969 * (m_z & 65535) + (m_z >> 16);
    m_w = 18000 * (m_w & 65535) + (m_w >> 16);

    return (m_z << 16) + m_w;
}
__global__ void fillArrayWithRandom(int* vector, int seed = 0)
{
    int i = threadIdx.x;
    vector[i] = pseudoRandomFunction(seed^i);
}

void Lab1(int* array, int size)
{
    int* gpuArray = 0;
    gpuErrorCheck(cudaSetDevice(0));
    gpuErrorCheck(cudaMalloc(&gpuArray, size));
    gpuErrorCheck(cudaMemcpy(gpuArray, array, size * sizeof(int), cudaMemcpyHostToDevice)); // <--- here is invalid argument exception!
    fillArrayWithRandom<<<1,size>>>(gpuArray,0);
    gpuErrorCheck(cudaGetLastError());
    gpuErrorCheck(cudaDeviceSynchronize());
    gpuErrorCheck(cudaMemcpy(array, gpuArray, size * sizeof(int), cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost));
    cudaFree(gpuArray);
    gpuErrorCheck(cudaDeviceReset());
}
```

I even tryed to change argument types but no progress...plese help! My gpu GeForce 9600GT, and cuda 6.5

Comment: Can you please post an output? Which `cudaMemcpy` produces an error?

Comment: `size` could be a problem (if it's larger than 512).  The arch switches you are using to compile could be a problem (you need to specify `-arch=sm_11` or similar).  SO expects, for questions like these, that you post an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).  Show the *whole* code, the compile command, and the entire output.  And actually, depending on which GPU you have, GeForce 9600 GT (a cc 1.0 device) may not work at all with CUDA 6.5.  Post the output from running the `deviceQuery` cuda sample code on your system.

Comment: You've already been advised of a [problem with your setup](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27361626/cuda-6-5-in-visual-studio-2013)

Comment: previous question worked when i changed command line architecture to 11. But this example doesn't work. In output i get: "invalid argument exception". Size is not larger than 512...it's 10

Comment: @eocron: Something doesn't add up. Your GPU is a GeForce 9600 GT, which is a compute capability 1.0 (sm_10) device. Support for sm_10 was removed in CUDA 6.5, and the `nvcc` from CUDA 6.5 will display an error message if you specify `-arch=sm_10'`: `nvcc fatal   : Value 'sm_10' is not defined for option 'gpu-architecture'`. Building with `-arch=sm_11` for use with an sm_10 device is just asking for trouble, as the device code is likely unable to execute on an sm_10 device. For what it's worth, I don't see proper status check for kernel execution in the above code. I would recommend adding it

Comment: I don't know. Wiki saying it's version is 1.1.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The only problem I can see is that this line is not correct:

```
gpuErrorCheck(cudaMalloc(&gpuArray, size));
```

it should be:

```
gpuErrorCheck(cudaMalloc(&gpuArray, size*sizeof(int)));
```

with that change, I can run your code without error, when `size` = 10.

Note that your `pseudoRandomFunction` routine does not use `seed`, so every value it creates will be the same.

Comment: omg....im a dumb.....how in the world did i miss this error?? maaan.....im reaaaly dumb....THX a lot!